# How to give File name as a command line argument in CLion

Tags: c++, file, command-line-arguments, clion

I need to read a file from the command line argument and then do some operations on its contents. I have written a small code to test it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::string;

    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: ./a.out Filename"
             << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::fstream input(argv[1], std::ios_base::in);
    string word;
    while(getline(input, word)) {
        cout << word;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine if I run it in the terminal by `./a.out filename.txt`

I am writing code in CLion so I need to give the filename/file-path in CLion as a command-line argument.

I tried adding the filename as an argument in Run -> Edit Configurations -> Program arguments but as far as I understand CLion is treating the `filename.txt` as a simple argument, not a filename. I also tried giving the path to the file but with no luck, CLion still does not read the file contents when I hit `run`.

Comment: "as far as I understand CLion is treating the filename.txt as a simple argument, not a filename" isnt that what you want? Your code takes a filename as arguments (a string), opens it and reads the file, you dont want to pass the contents of the file as argument to your code

Comment: I mean rather than reading the file contents it simply terminates with `exit code 0` while on the terminal it's working fine?

Comment: you are not checking for errors when opening the file. Probably the file is not in the working directory. Do you use an absolute or relative path?

Comment: `if (! input.open()) { std::cout << "file is not open"; }`

Comment: I have tried both relative and absolute paths, it's not reading in any of the cases.

Comment: "you are not checking for errors when opening the file." then why it's working fine in the CLion terminal?

Comment: you should also print the command line argument in your code to know where the actual problem is, I still bet on the file opening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221376/discussion-between-arun-suryan-and-idclev-463035818).